# How to find a non fredholm operator with a generalized inverse?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let E,F be Banach spaces. An operator B ∈ B(F,E) is called a generalized inverse of A ∈ B(E,F) if ABA = A and BAB = B?

How do I find a non Fredholm operator with a generalized inverse? I actually dont have much examples of non fredholm operators but I think instead of randomly looking for them and trying to find out whether it has a generalized inverse , a better idea is to start with a fredholm operator and turn it non fredholm such that it has a generalized inverse. Is there a way to do this?

Note: Fredholm operators are bounded. Some text may not require this but this is the definition I am using.

Comment: Interesting - do you mean to imply all Fredholm operators have generalised inverses? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: A reference: H. Heuser: Functionalanalysis , §24.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E=F=H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Then it is well-known that for a bounded linear operator $A$ on $H$ we have:

$A$ has a generalized inverse if and only if $im(A)$ is closed.

Hence look for an operator $A$ with $ im(A)$ is closed and $ \dim ker(A)= \infty$.

Such an operator $A$ is not Fredholm.

Comment: Hi Fred . Thanks for the answer. Is there a name of a reference for that theorem you mentioned . I have actually never seen that before